# Tensorflow Lite Model Maker throws errors on import

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to make tf lite work but it has some import problem
as I type :
`Import tflite_model_maker` to python

It throws these errors:
`/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflowjs/read_weights.py:28: FutureWarning: In the future` np.object`will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar. np.uint8, np.uint16, np.object, np.bool] Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/home/miscope/examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package/src/tflite_model_maker/__init__.py", line 44, in <module> from tflite_model_maker import audio_classifier File "/home/miscope/examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package/src/tflite_model_maker/audio_classifier/__init__.py", line 24, in <module> from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.data_util.audio_dataloader import DataLoader File "/home/miscope/examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package/src/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/audio_dataloader.py", line 27, in <module> from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task.model_spec import audio_spec File "/home/miscope/examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package/src/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_spec/__init__.py", line 20, in <module> from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task.model_spec import audio_spec File "/home/miscope/examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package/src/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_spec/audio_spec.py", line 30, in <module> from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task import model_util File "/home/miscope/examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package/src/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_util.py", line 28, in <module> from tensorflowjs.converters import converter as tfjs_converter File "/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflowjs/__init__.py", line 21, in <module> from tensorflowjs import converters File "/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/__init__.py", line 21, in <module> from tensorflowjs.converters.converter import convert File "/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py", line 35, in <module> from tensorflowjs.converters import keras_h5_conversion as conversion File "/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/keras_h5_conversion.py", line 33, in <module> from tensorflowjs import write_weights  # pylint: disable=import-error File "/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflowjs/write_weights.py", line 25, in <module> from tensorflowjs import read_weights File "/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflowjs/read_weights.py", line 28, in <module> np.uint8, np.uint16, np.object, np.bool] File "/home/miscope/miniconda3/envs/sencondenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 305, in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr]) AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'.`np.object`was a deprecated alias for the builtin`object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use` object `by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations`

I think I installed all the required package
with the setup.py
from this repo (pip_packages) https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker

I'm using miniconda with python3.9.2

I don't even know if I can use tf lite model maker outside of google colab.

I would like to train a custom object detection model like this but outside of colab.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Train_custom_model_tutorial.ipynb

I hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: Hi @user20659597, The error message suggests that there is a version incompatibility issue with the numpy module.  To fix the issue, you can try upgrading your numpy version to the latest version with this code `pip install --upgrade numpy` and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!

Comment: tflite model maker only works with numpy 1.20.3 becasue of some kind of reference problem

Comment: I posted this issue on the tensorflow forum and they told me I should report this bug on github

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try decreasing the version of numpy:

```
pip install numpy==1.20.3
```

Comment: I have install same numpy version and install tflite model maker but still i am getting this error.
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'.
`np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `object` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
when i import (from tflite_model_maker import model_spec)